# How to write Django query to grab all objects in descending order according to two number fields?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I'm using Django. i'm trying to write query according to the top rated products. i have product table. as you can see below.

```
class Product(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name=_("Owner"), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(_("Name"), max_length=150,null=True)  
    average_rating  =models.DecimalField(_("average rating"), max_digits=10, decimal_places=2,null=True,blank=True)
    total_reviews = models.IntegerField(_("total reviews "),default=0,null=True,blank=True)
    is_remove = models.BooleanField(_("Remove"), default=False)
    create_time = models.DateTimeField(_("Create time"), default=timezone.now)
```

Now i want to get all objects which have highest average rating and total count.

I have tried many things below. but none of them worked.

1 -

```
 def get_all_top_rated_products(self):
     query = self.filter(is_remove=False).order_by("total_reviews","average_rating")
     print(query)
     return query
```

2

```
 def get_all_top_rated_products(self):
     query = self.filter(is_remove=False).aggregate(Max('average_rating'),Max('total_reviews'))
     print(query)
     return query
```

Comment: What do you mean with *which have highest average rating and total count.*, you can only order by one criterion, the second one is only used in case of a tie breaker.

Comment: Like I want to write a query that returns the top rated products. that is a goal i want to achieve.

Comment: I have spent time on it but i unable to do so. How just alibaba and other ecommerce show top rated products..

Answer (score 1):

You should order in *descending order*, you can do this by prefixing the fieldname with a minus (`-`):

```
def get_all_top_rated_products(self):
    return self.filter(is_remove=False).order_by(
        '-average_rating', '-total_reviews'
    )
```